# Error install "npm install" bootstrap 4 ( build tools )

Tags: npm

I setup build tools for study. But i installed nodejs and go to cmd for setup with "npm install", it show me an error. How can i fix this?

Tks.

Error info:

C:\Users\users\Downloads\bootstrap-custom>npm install

> iltorb@1.3.10 install C:\Users\micha\Downloads\bootstrap-custom\node_modules\iltorb
>   detect-libc prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 2.5.1
prebuild-install info looking for local prebuild @ prebuilds\iltorb-v1.3.10-node-v59-win32-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ C:\Users\users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_prebuilds\https-github.com-MayhemYDG-iltorb-releases-download-v1.3.10-iltorb-v1.3.10-node-v59-win32-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/MayhemYDG/iltorb/releases/download/v1.3.10/iltorb-v1.3.10-node-v59-win32-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install http 404 https://github.com/MayhemYDG/iltorb/releases/download/v1.3.10/iltorb-v1.3.10-node-v59-win32-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=9.11.1 runtime=node arch=x64 platform=win32)

C:\Users\users\Downloads\bootstrap-custom\node_modules\iltorb>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:170:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\micha\Downloads\bootstrap-custom\node_modules\iltorb
gyp ERR! node -v v9.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN rollback Rolling back readable-stream@2.2.9 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\users\Downloads\bootstrap-custom\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm WARN bootstrap@4.1.0 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! iltorb@1.3.10 install: `detect-libc prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the iltorb@1.3.10 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-04-10T11_50_16_425Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

At least one of your problems is that your bootstrap package requires jQuery 1.9.1 or above, see the package.json file

```
"peerDependencies": {
 "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3",
 "popper.js": "^1.14.0"   },
```

So all you really need to do is install jQuery and re-run **npm install** on your bootstrap package. So something like this should do it:-

```
# get back to the directory where your bootstrap package is
cd bootstrap-4.1.0
# install latest version of jQuery  
npm i jquery
# re-install the bootstrap package
npm install
```

(I notice you are on Windows so do the equivalent of the above.) Go through all your packages that are in error or have a warning and make sure that they are installed.